# Sometimes can't delete item in listview-sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I create a listview in Android. My listview data is from sqlite database. When user click the item on the list. Alert dialog to delete confirmation will appear.
this is my code to delete from list:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(todaycode.this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Delete from list");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure to delete?");

    final int del_position=position;
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
             //delete from database     
             mDb.deleteContact(list_food.get(+ del_position).getId());
             //reload
             final ArrayList<food_object> list_food = mDb.getAllfood();
             final ListView list;
             final String[] food_name = new String[list_food.size()];

             for(int i=0;i<list_food.size();i++){
                 food_name[i]=list_food.get(i).getName();}

             Integer[] imageId = {
                 R.drawable.image1,};

             final customlist adapter = new customlist(todaycode.this, food_name, imageId);
             list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listToday);
             list.setAdapter(adapter);
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
       });
```

and this is my code to delete from my database in DBAdapter:

```
public boolean deleteContact(int id)
    {
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, COL_ID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
    }
```

this code is work. but sometimes user can't delete an item from the list until they reload this activity (move to other activity and back). The Alert dialog is appear, but after  user click "Yes" there's nothing happen.

this only happen sometime. And only occure in one item on the list, so if user choose other item on the list to delete, it's still working. does anybody knows why this is happen?

**EDITED**

after many try, I conclude that the error (the item can't deleted) always started after user delete the second item (user deleting consecutively), and I'm still no idea why this is happen

this is my DBAdapter code, I simplified it [See the Code](http://pastebin.com/M5pHxdPA)

this is my customlist code [See the Code](http://pastebin.com/PSwBrxcP)

Comment: Did you try my suggestion to load your data from your database in an ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you probably use autoincrement id in your table. When you get the id from the setOnItemClick it's actually the index of the item and not the id. So when you delete one at index 3 that id will be deleted and next time you want to delete at same index there won't be an item whit that id.

Comment: yes, great thanks, this is the cause of my problem.
but I can't find the solution :/ any idea? I have tried to disable the autoincrement but still not work

Comment: Well im sorry but I haven't figured that one out myself exactly. I think you must try to get the data you picked rather then the index of the picked item. I'll let you know if I find a way!

Comment: I don't know if you load your database list in an ArrayList? But if you do you could use the index of the picked item to get the index of the object in the ArrayList and then get the id of the object.

Comment: The index of the array is the same as the index of the item in de list. When you delete an item from your database you should refresh your array first and then refresh the listview. Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

put this listener it will work then bro..!

```
 alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
         //delete from database     
         mDb.deleteContact(list_food.get(+ del_position).getId());
         //reload
         final ArrayList<food_object> list_food = mDb.getAllfood();
         final ListView list;
         final String[] food_name = new String[list_food.size()];

         for(int i=0;i<list_food.size();i++){
             food_name[i]=list_food.get(i).getName();}

         Integer[] imageId = {
             R.drawable.image1,};

         final customlist adapter = new customlist(todaycode.this, food_name, imageId);
         list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listToday);
         list.setAdapter(null);
         list.setAdapter(adapter);
         }
   });
```

Comment: Ok then please post your complete related code..and also the adapter code

Comment: the adapter code was posted, I don't know what other code do you need, I think the adapter is the only one that related

Comment: no you have not posted the code.the code for customList class i.e adapter